# Derivation of first-order derivatives (gradient vector) for multivariate ordinal regression cutpoints log-posterior

Tags: regression, bayesian, multivariate-analysis, ordinal-data

Throughout this post:

- $t$ is an index for the $t$-th outcome variable, and there are a total of $T$ outcomes
- $n$ is an index for the $n$-th individual, and there are a total of $N$ individuals,
- $C_{t,k}$ denotes the $k$-th cutpoint parameter for outcome variable $t$, which has $K_{t}$ categories.
- We are including $- \infty$ and  $+ \infty$ in the cutpoint parameter set, therefore we have a total of $K_{t} + 1$ cutpoints for each outcome variable $t$.
- Column vectors are denoted by underlining (e.g. $\underline{X}$) and row vectors by $\underline{X}'$.
- Matrices are denoted by bold font (e.g. $\mathbf{\Omega}$).
- $\Phi$ denotes the CDF of a standard normal and $\phi$ the PDF

For each individual $n$, we have an observed ordinal outcome row vector of length $T$ such that $\underline{Y}_{n}'$ = $\left[Y_{n,1} ~ \ldots ~ Y_{n,K_{T}} \right]$ so there are a total of $NT$ observed data points.

For binary outcomes there are only two categories - $K_t$ = 2 -  $Y_{n,t}$ is either 1 for a negative result or 2 for a positive result - and each cutpoint parameter is either $C_{t,0}$ = - $\infty$, $C_{t,1}$ = 0, or $C_{t,2}$ =  $+ \infty$.

$\mathbf{X_n}'$ is the design matrix and $\underline{\beta^{*}}$ is the full covariate vector of length $Tp$ - which is formed by stacking all of the individual covariate vectors $\underline{\beta}_{t}$ for each of the $T$ outcomes on top of one another.

**Latent data**

We augment each observed data vector $\underline{Y}_{n}'$  with a continuous latent vector $\underline{Z}_{n}'$ = $\left[Z_{n,1} ~ \ldots ~ Z_{n,K_{T}} \right]$ which has a truncated multivariate normal distribution with mean vector $\underline{X}' \underline\beta^{*},  $ and a $T$-dimensional variance-covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Omega}$ equal to a correlation matrix (for identifiability) truncated in the interval $ I\left[\underline{C}_{y_{n} - 1}, \underline{C}_{y_{n}} \right] $:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\underline{Z}_{n}' \sim \text{multi_normal}\left(\mathbf{X_n}' \underline{\beta^{*}}, \mathbf{\Omega} \right)
\cdot 
I\left[\underline{C}_{y_{n} - 1}, \underline{C}_{y_{n}} \right] 
\end{aligned}
\label{augmented_data}
\end{equation}

The relationship between the observed ordinal data vector $\underline{Y}_{n}'$ and the augmented latent data vector $\underline{Z}_{n}'$ is:

${Y}_{n,t} = k$ $\implies$ ${C}_{y_{n} - 1, t} < {Z}_{n,t}' < {C}_{y_{n}, t}$

We can sample the latent data from each univariate conditional distribution: (note that $-t$ means "all but the "$t$-th):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
{Z}_{n,t} | \underline{Z}_{n,-t} &\sim \text{univariate_normal} \left(\mu_{n,T}, \sigma_{n,T} \right)
\cdot 
I\left[\underline{C}_{y_{n,t} - 1}, \underline{C}_{y_{n,t}} \right] 
\end{aligned}
\label{MVN_full_conditionals}
\end{equation}

Where:

$
\mu_{n,t} = 
\mathbf{X_n}' \underline\beta +
\underline\Omega_{t, -t} \cdot 
\boldsymbol\Omega^{-1}_{-t, -t} \cdot
\left( \underline{Z}_{-t}  - X_{n}' \underline\beta_{-t} \right)
$, and

$
\sigma^{2}_{n,t} = 
\Omega^{-1}_{t, t}  - 
\underline\Omega_{t, -t} \cdot 
\boldsymbol\Omega^{-1}_{-t, -t} \cdot
\underline\Omega'_{t, -t} 
$

**Log-likelihood and conditional log-posterior distribution of log-differences**

The \textbf{log-likelihood} for each individual $n$ is expressed as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
LL\left( \text{Parameters} | \underline{Y}_{n}' \right) &= 
\sum_{t=1}^{T}
\text{log}\left[
 \Phi\left( \frac{C_{y_n}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right)  -  
 \Phi\left( \frac{C_{y_n - 1} - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) 
\right]
\end{aligned}
\label{log_likelihood}
\end{equation}

We can write the full conditional log-density of the cutpoint parameters as (assuming uniform prior for now to simplify the calculations) :

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\log\left(\pi \left( \underline{C_t} |  \underline{\beta}, \mathbf{\Omega},  \underline{Z}_{-t}  \right)\right)  & \propto
\sum_{n | Y_n = 1}
\text{log}\left[
 \Phi\left( \frac{C_{t,1}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right)  
\right]
\\ &\cdot
\sum_{n | Y_n = 2}
\text{log}\left[
 \Phi\left( \frac{C_{t,2}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right)  -  
 \Phi\left( \frac{C_{t,1}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) 
\right]
\\ &\vdots
\\ &\cdot
\sum_{n | Y_n = K}
\text{log}\left[
 1 -  
 \Phi\left( \frac{C_{t,K-1}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) 
\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

In order to use a gradient-based algorithm such as MALA we need to re-parameterise the cutpoints so that they are unconstrained. We can do this by re-parameterising them as log-differences:

$
\delta_{t,k} = \log(C_{t,k} - C_{t,k-1})  ~ \text{(for k = 2,... , K-1,  so K-2 log-differences for each outcome)}
$

i.e. for k = 2,... , K-1:

$
C_{t,k} = C_{t,1} + \sum_{k'=2}^{k} \exp(\delta_{t,k'}) = \sum_{k'=2}^{k}  \exp(\delta_{t,k'}) ~ \text{(as fixing first cutpoint to 0)}
$

And the log absolute determinant of the Jacobian adjustment to account for the transformation is:

$
\log(|J|) = \sum_{k=2}^{K-1}  \delta_{t,k}
$

Therefore, the full conditional posterior density of the log-differences if given as the sum of the log-posterior of the cutpoints and the log absolute determinant of the Jacobian:

$
\log\left(\pi \left( \underline{\delta_t} |  \underline{\beta}, \mathbf{\Omega},  \underline{Z}_{-t}  \right)\right)  =
\log\left(\pi \left( \underline{C_t} |  \underline{\beta}, \mathbf{\Omega},  \underline{Z}_{-t}  \right)\right)  + 
\sum_{k=2}^{K-1}  \delta_{t,k}
$

**Attempt at calculating gradient vector (first-order partial derivatives)**

I want to calculate the partial derivatives of the log-posterior of the log-differences w.r.t each log difference, i.e.:
$
\frac{ \partial \log\left(\pi \left( \underline{\delta_t} |  \underline{\beta}, \mathbf{\Omega},  \underline{Z}_{-t}  \right)\right) }{ \partial {\delta_{t, k}}  }  = 
\frac{ \partial \log\left(\pi \left( \underline{C_t} |  \underline{\beta}, \mathbf{\Omega},  \underline{Z}_{-t}  \right)\right)  }{ \partial {\delta_{t, k}}  }  + 
\frac{ \partial }{ \partial {\delta_{t, k}}  }   \sum_{k=2}^{K-1}  \delta_{t,k}  
$

Note that the second term of the partial derivatives (i.e. the derivatives of the Jacobian adjustment) will vanish.

The last log-difference ($\delta_{t, K-1}$) is only included in the expression for $C_{t, K-1}$  so the partial derivative w.r.t this parameter is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{ \partial \log\left(\pi \left( \underline{\delta_t} |  \underline{\beta}, \mathbf{\Omega},  \underline{Z}_{-t}  \right)\right) }{ \partial {\delta_{t, K-1}}  }   
\\
%%%%%%%% term 1
&= \sum_{n | Y_n = K}  {\left[- \phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-1} - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) \cdot \text{exp}(\delta_{t, K-1}) / \sigma_{n,t} \right]}  \Big/  {\left[ 1 -  \Phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-1}  - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right)\right]} 
\\
%%%%%%%% term 2
&+ \sum_{n | Y_n = K-1}  \cfrac{\left[ \phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-1} - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) \cdot \text{exp}(\delta_{t, K-1}) / \sigma_{n,t} -   
\Phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-2} - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right)   \right]}{\left[
 \Phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-1}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right)  -  
 \Phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-2}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) 
\right]}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The second-to-last log-difference ($\delta_{t, K-2}$) is included in the expression for both $C_{t, K-1}$  and $C_{t, K-2}$, so the partial derivative w.r.t this parameter is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{ \partial \log\left(\pi \left( \underline{\delta_t} |  \underline{\beta}, \mathbf{\Omega},  \underline{Z}_{-t}  \right)\right) }{ \partial {\delta_{t, K-2}}  }   
\\
\\
%%%%% term 1
&= \sum_{n | Y_n = K}  {\left[- \phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-1} - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) \cdot \text{exp}(\delta_{t, K-2}) / \sigma_{n,t} \right]}  \Big/  {\left[ 1 -  \Phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-1}  - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right)\right]} 
\\
%%%%%%% term 2
&+ \sum_{n | Y_n = K-1}  \cfrac{\left[ \phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-1} - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) \cdot \text{exp}(\delta_{t, K-2})  / \sigma_{n,t} -   
\phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-2} - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) \cdot \text{exp}(\delta_{t, K-2}) / \sigma_{n,t} \right]}{\left[
 \Phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-1}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right)  -  
 \Phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-2}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) 
\right]}
\\
%%%%%%% term 3
&+ \sum_{n | Y_n = K-2}  \cfrac{\left[ \phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-2} - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) \cdot \text{exp}(\delta_{t, K-2})  / \sigma_{n,t} -   
\Phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-3} - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right)   \right]}{\left[
 \Phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-2}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right)  -  
 \Phi\left( \cfrac{C_{t,K-3}     - \mu_{n,t}}{\sigma_{n,t}} \right) 
\right]}
\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

And we carry on like this for the remaining derivatives, so the partial derivative w.r.t ($\delta_{t, K-3}$) will have 4 sums, ($\delta_{t, K-4}$) will have 5 sums, etc.

However the results I am getting are not matching results obtained via automatic differentiation (done in C++ using Stan math library). The reason why I am calculating derivatives manually is because I am looking at implementing RHMC which requires calculating third-order derivatives and from what I have heard autodiff tends to be less efficient at higher-order derivatives.

Is there an error somewhere in the derivation?

Comment: Finding errors in lengthy calculations can be tedious. I doubt if anyone here will make the effort to find the errors for you. A better approach might to be start with a simpler problem, make sure you can calculate it correctly, and than proceed in small increments until you get to the full problem.

Comment: @J.Delaney Nevermind I worked it out! Some of the CDF terms vanish and I left them in accidentally. Now time to compute Hessian and 3rd order derivatives....